# Need an advice for per user based ACL

Tags: zend-framework2, acl

Currently I'm working on system, that uses ZendFramework2 Acl implementation for managing user roles and permissions for various parts of it. Till this moment it works as is supposed to do - giving or rejecting users based on their role. Recently we got a new feature request - implement functionality that allows permission management per user, regardless the role he or she has. Here comes the tricky part - Zend implementation of Acl doesn't met the requirements out of the box (if it supposed to do so at al). Just to note - system is already tightly integrated with the current model, so it will be pain of heart to use another kind permission management model.

So far the best solution I could think of was to represent individual users as roles in Acl and grant them appropriate privileges, so it is possible to dynamically create or delete resources and privileges for users, without impacting overall role permissions (which still apply).

Could I get some suggestions please? Is this the "right way" or there better approach to the problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Totally, how many user is going to use your system? If it is something large amount try to group the user based on roles.

Answer (score 0):

If an user by the fact to be himself has some privilegies, then you have to create a new role for that user.

I have just developed an ACL module that allows you to manage access to each route only creating a new key in each route called 'roles'. You do not have to configure the ACL creating allow rules manually, this module creates the rules automatically for you reading the routes.

You can have a look: https://github.com/itrascastro/TrascastroACL